# wordpress and htaccess 301 redirect without admin

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect my entire blog to a new domain without redirecting the admin area.
The code I use is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^old-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But still I'm getting redirected to the new domain when I go to old-domain.com/wp-admin

Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess here?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-admin$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Almost. change in the second line old-domain to new-domain and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

```
# Redirect all requests except wp-admin
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-includes/.*|wp-admin/.*|wp-content/.*)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```